# Sort a list of dictionaries by a common key and moving unknown values to end

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I have a function that returns a key function for sorted(), for which the target is a list of dicts. A working example is:

```
def sort2key(sortKey, **kwargs):

    def attrgetter(obj):
        try:
            theItem = obj[sortKey]
        except:
            theItem = None
        finally:
            return theItem

    return attrgetter

input = [
    {'id':0, 'x': 2, 'y': 2},
    {'id':1, 'x': 1, 'y': 0},
    {'id':2, 'x': 0, 'y': 1}
]

theSort = {'sortKey': 'x'}

output = sorted(input, key=sort2key(**theSort))

print(input)
print(output)

>>> [{'x': 2, 'id': 0, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'id': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'id': 2, 'y': 1}]
>>> [{'x': 0, 'id': 2, 'y': 1}, {'x': 1, 'id': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'id': 0, 'y': 2}]
```

---

However I want the function to be able to handle missing values:

```
[
    {'id':0, 'x': 2, 'y': 2},
    {'id':1, 'x': 1, 'y': 0},
    {'id':2,         'y': 1}
]
```

But the previous code would force the dict with the missing x to the start - it needs to be either start or end depending on the sort setting:

```
{'sortKey': 'x', 'unknowns': 'toEnd'} or 
{'sortKey': 'x', 'unknowns': 'toStart'}
```

Furthermore, the value of x in this case are numbers, but they could be strings or other types.

---

Is there a way to force unknown values to the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda function and the `get` method of `dict` type. Here is your code :

```
  Input = [
      {'id':0, 'x': 2, 'y': 2},
      {'id':1, 'x': 1, 'y': 0},
      {'id':2, 'x': 0, 'y': 1}  ]

  sortKey = 'id' # Use max for ToEnd setting
  unknown = max( [ elt[sortKey] for elt in Input if sortKey in elt ] )  

  Output  = sorted(Input, key=lambda X: X.get(sortKey, unknown))

  for elt in Output:
     print(elt)
```

dict.get(a, b) returns the value associated to key a if it exists or the default value b.

For mixed data you can use : `max( [ str(elt[sortKey]) for elt in Input if sortKey in elt ] )` so it will be possible to compare different types values.

You can switch between ToEnd and ToStart settings just by using `min`/`max` functions.

Comment: In python 3.4 you would be referring to the dict.get(a,b) method. However your reply does raise a good point. I might not necessarily have numbers so using 'inf' won't work. The value could be a string - I'll update the question.

Comment: You are right. we have the choice between `get` and `setdefault`, the former method provides the value but don't change the `dict` as `setdefault` do. For the `ToEnd` and `ToStart` setting you can add a min\max function so the missing element will always be direct to Start\end position. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks nino, using min()/max() for various types is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using @nino_701's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36914647/4568456)

```
def sort2key(sortKey, minVal, maxVal, unknowns='toEnd', **kwargs):

    def attrgetter(obj):
        try:
            theItem = obj[sortKey]
        except:
            theItem = minVal if unknowns == 'toStart' else maxVal
        finally:
            return theItem

    return attrgetter

input = [
    {'id':0, 'x': 2, 'y': 2},
    {'id':1,         'y': 0},
    {'id':2, 'x': 0, 'y': 1}
]

theSort = {'sortKey': 'x'}

minVal = min((x[theSort['sortKey']] for x in input if theSort['sortKey'] in x))
maxVal = max((x[theSort['sortKey']] for x in input if theSort['sortKey'] in x))

output = sorted(input, key=sort2key(minVal = minVal, maxVal = maxVal, unknowns='toStart', **theSort))
output2 = sorted(input, key=sort2key(minVal = minVal, maxVal = maxVal, unknowns='toEnd', **theSort))

print(input)
print(output)
print(output2)

>>> [{'id': 0, 'y': 2, 'x': 2}, {'id': 1, 'y': 0}, {'id': 2, 'y': 1, 'x': 0}]
>>> [{'id': 1, 'y': 0}, {'id': 2, 'y': 1, 'x': 0}, {'id': 0, 'y': 2, 'x': 2}]
>>> [{'id': 2, 'y': 1, 'x': 0}, {'id': 0, 'y': 2, 'x': 2}, {'id': 1, 'y': 0}]
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that I have to manually provide the minVal and maxVal each time - I would prefer not to have to do this.